# If I tap a notification in the android app I can't press back to exit

Tags: bug, status-completed, notifications, android-app

If the app isn't running and I get a notification when I tap it I get the notification feed, but I can't press back to exit the app or close the notifications.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Oh boy, that was a bad one! It was not just that coming in from a push notification was blocking leaving but that having the notifications panel opened at all blocked the back button's press due to some over eager logic in the implementation of the `DrawerLayout` from Google.

This is fixed and will go out in the next app update, thanks!